# Including an AND statement in a Python List Comprehension

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension

I'm trying to create a function for an array. The array will go in and if the value is 0 it will be put to the back of the list. My function works most of the time, but the only issue is that the Boolean value False keeps getting interpreted as 0. I've created an AND statement to differentiate 0 and False, but it is not working, and I can't figure out why. Can you not have AND statements in list comprehension?

```
def move_zeros(array):
    [array.insert(len(array), array.pop(array.index(x))) for x in array if x == 0 and x is not False]
    return array
```

I've added two examples.One works. The other doesn't for what I'd like to accomplish.

Input: [1,"a", 2, 0, 3, "b"] Output: [1, "a", 2, 3, "b", 0] This works

Input: [1, False, 2, 0, 3, "b"] Output: [1, 2, 3, "b", False, 0] This doesn't work, because False is being moved to the end of the list when I want to pass over it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what your function is doing with examples? Btw, you are creating an array of `None`s as insert doesn't return a value. Also `array.insert(len(array), ...)` is same as `array.append(...)`.

Comment: You should learn to use list comprehensions. That's not how they are used. Quick rule of thumb: if your list comprehension has side effects, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Add an example `array` (list I assume) that gives you problems.  And what result you want.  You should `return` the list comprehension, not some list that gets modified within the comprehension.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go as far as saying a list comprehension should have no side effects, buy you certainly shouldn't discard the list it creates immediately.

Comment: Why might there be a `False` in the list?  `0` and `False` are the same in so many contexts, that is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Input: [1,"a", 2, 0, 3, "b"] Output: [1, "a", 2, 3, "b", 0] This works

Comment: Input: [1, False, 2, 0, 3, "b"] Output: [1, 2, 3, "b", False, 0] This doesn't work, because False is being moved to the end of the list when I want to pass over it.

Comment: The problem is in the `array.index(x)` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop alternative to your list comprehension.  It still modifies the list.  As noted by others `x is 0` simplifies the distinction between `0` and `False`:

```
In [106]: al=[0, 1, 2, False, True, 3,0,10]
In [107]: for i,x in enumerate(al):
     ...:     if x is 0:
     ...:         value = al.pop(i)
     ...:         al.append(value)
     ...:         
In [108]: al
Out[108]: [1, 2, False, True, 3, 10, 0, 0]
```

With side effects like this, a loop is better than a comprehension.  A comprehension should be used in the:

```
return [.... for x in al if ...]
```

sense.  You could also use enumerate in the comprehension:

```
return [fun(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(al) if x...]
```

In a clear list comprehension, the list will only appear once; tests and returned values will depend only on the iteration variables, not the original list.

===================

Beware that `0` and `False` are often treated as the same.  For example operations that expect numbers treat `False` as `0`, and `True` as 1.  And functions that expect booleans will treat `0` as `False`.

```
In [117]: [x+1 for x in al]
Out[117]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 11]
In [118]: al=[0, 1, 2, False, True, 3,0,10]
In [119]: sum(al)
Out[119]: 17
```

=================

Example with `and` in list comprehension:

```
In [137]: [x for x in al if x==0]
Out[137]: [0, False, 0]
In [138]: [x for x in al if x==0 and x is not False]
Out[138]: [0, 0]
In [140]: [x for x in al if not (x==0 and x is not False)]
Out[140]: [1, 2, False, True, 3, 10]
```

============

Another possible test - of the str representation:

```
In [143]: [x for x in al if str(x)!='0']
Out[143]: [1, 2, False, True, 3, 10]
```

================

Your problem isn't with the test, but with the `al.index(x)`; it's matching both `0` and `False`, and removing the first, regardless of which `x` is passing your test.

Version with `al.index(x)`:

```
In [396]: al=[1,False,2, 0,3,"b"]
In [397]: for x in al:
     ...:     if x ==0 and x is not False:
     ...:         al.append(al.pop(al.index(x)))
     ...:         
In [398]: al
Out[398]: [1, 2, 0, 3, 'b', False]
```

Version with enumerate `i`

```
In [399]: al=[1,False,2, 0,3,"b"]
In [400]: for i,x in enumerate(al):
     ...:     if x ==0 and x is not False:
     ...:         al.append(al.pop(i))
     ...:         
In [401]: al
Out[401]: [1, False, 2, 3, 'b', 0]
```

Or in your function:

```
def move_zeros(array):
   [array.insert(len(array), array.pop(i)) for i,x in enumerate(array) if (x == 0 and x is not False)]
   return array

In [403]: al=[1,False,2, 0,3,"b"]
In [404]: move_zeros(al)
Out[404]: [1, False, 2, 3, 'b', 0]
```

testing the `index` in isolation:

```
In [405]: al=[1,False,2, 0,3,"b"]
In [406]: al.index(0)
Out[406]: 1
In [407]: al.index(False)
Out[407]: 1
```

Comment: `x is 0` is implementation-dependent; there is no guarantee that `x is 0` will be true just because `x == 0`.

Comment: Yes, in `cpython` (the main one), integers below 256 are unique, and the `is` works.  In `pypy` that might not be the case (I recall a bug/issue revolving around that difference).

Comment: It could be argued that a list that contains both `0` and `False`, and expects them to treated differently, is asking for trouble of some sort.

Comment: My main question is if you can even add an AND statement into the list comprehension. As long as it checks whether x ==0 and x is not False it should work. 0 is not False == True. Where as False is not False == False.

Comment: Yes, the whole `if` phase, including the `and` is considered when iterating in a list comprehension.  See my edit.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you could test the string representation of the iterator, `str(x)`.

Comment: I tried the string representation of the iterator (great idea), but for some reason it still is evaluating false as '0' in this case. I've tested with print(str(False)) and gotten 'False'. I'm wondering now if there is some limitation to list comprehensions ability in regards to boolean values.

Comment: The problem isn't with your `if` test, it's with the `array.index(x)`.  See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a bad idea to try to make a semantic distinctions between `0` and `False` when filtering a list, but if you have a good reason to do so there are a couple of ways that might work in your situation.

A somewhat hackish approach which works in CPython is to use `is` rather than `==`:

```
def move_zeros(array):
    zeros = 0
    new_array = []
    for x in array:
        if not x is 0:
            new_array.append(x)
        else:
            zeros += 1
    return new_array + [0]*zeros
```

As @chepner points out, this is implementation dependent. A more robust approach which works in Python 3 is to use `isinstance()`:

```
def move_zeros(array):
    zeros = 0
    new_array = []
    for x in array:
        if x != 0 or isinstance(x,bool):
            new_array.append(x)
        else:
            zeros += 1
    return new_array + [0]*zeros
```

Using either definition:

```
>>> move_zeros([1, False, 2, 0, 3, "b"])
[1, False, 2, 3, 'b', 0]
```

Comment: This is implementation-dependent.